# Connecting MongoDB and a flutter Mobile application

Tags: database, mongodb, flutter, mobile-application

How to configure the database connection to the flutter app and retrieve data from the database to be shown in the app?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [MongoDB dart package](https://pub.dev/packages/mongo_dart) that you can use

I would recommend that you utilize the Flutter [BLoC](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/) pattern as a way to display your data and handling state changes. But if you are handling something on a simpler scale you could simply retrieve the data and update it in a stateful widget.